# Creating a custom BindableProperty that takes a custom defined string representation of the underlying return type in XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I am attempting to create a custom `BindableProperty` for a custom view which takes in a string when consumed through XAML but is internally implemented as a custom structure as follows:

```
struct X {
   public Y A;
   public Z B;
   // Y and Z are data types
   // pertaining to a struct
}
public class MyView : CustomView {
  public static readonly BindableProperty 
      MyValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create
                         (propertyName: "MyValue",
                          returnType: typeof(string),
                          declaringType: typeof(MyView),
                          defaultValue: null,
                          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                          propertyChanged: MyValuePropertyChanged);
  static void MyValuePropertyChanged(BindableObject obj, object oldValue, object newValue) {
    MyView view = (MyView)obj;
    string enteredStringValue = (string)newValue;
    // Set the MyValue field as required
  }
  public X MyValue {
      // Implement getters and setters
  }
}
```

My initial instinct to create the aforementioned property was to declare the above fields and generate the required instance of struct `X` with respect to the `string` passed in XAML in the `MyValuePropertyChanged` method, but it is deemed impossible as an exception is thrown during runtime denoting the illegality of such declaration.

In synopsis, I am attempting to replicate the behavior of the `Xamarin.Forms.GridLength` structure whose string representations in XAML code is converted to the required structure when accessed through the getters and setters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The said behavior can be implemented by defining a custom type converter via inheritance of the `Xamarin.Forms.TypeConverter` class and decorating the aforementioned custom converter by the `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversion` attribute and the concerned structure by the `Xamarin.Forms.TypeConverter` attribute as follows:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty 
      MyValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create
                         (propertyName: nameof(MyValue),
                          returnType: typeof(X),
                          declaringType: typeof(MyView),
                          defaultValue: null,
                          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                          propertyChanged: MyValuePropertyChanged);
[TypeConverter(typeof(XConverter))]
struct X; // Declaration omitted in answer

[TypeConversion(typeof(X))]
class XConverter : TypeConverter {
   public override object 
        ConvertFromInvariantString(string value) {
      if (value == null) return null;
      
      // Return the object corresponding to the passed
      // string representation of the said object
   }
}
```

A predefined converter by Xamarin can also be used when needed as follows:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty
   SizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create
                  (propertyName: nameof(Size),
                   returnType: typeof(double),
                   declaringType: typeof(TestClass));
[TypeConverter(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.FontSizeConverter))]
public double Size {
   get => (double)GetValue(SizeProperty);
   set => SetValue(SizeProperty, value);
}
```